# Calculate TIMESTAMP difference from one column for each group

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to **calculate time difference in minutes between MAX(DateTime) and MIN(DateTime) for each group.**

Example:

```
DateTime                  Group_ID
2019-03-21 10:58:34 UTC     1
2019-03-21 10:58:44 UTC     1
2019-03-21 10:58:54 UTC     2
2019-03-21 10:59:04 UTC     1
2019-03-21 10:59:14 UTC     2
2019-03-21 10:59:24 UTC     2
2019-03-21 10:59:34 UTC     2
2019-03-21 10:59:44 UTC     1
2019-03-21 10:59:54 UTC     1 
...
```

I unsuccessfully tried with these queries:

```
Select Group_ID,
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(DateTime, DateTime, MINUTE) as timeDiff
from `xx.yy.zz`
group by Group_ID
```

/*

```
Select Group_ID, 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
      DateTime, 
      LAG(DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Group_ID ORDER BY DateTime), 
      MINUTE
    ) Working_Hours
from `xx.yy.zz`
```

I assume there is a trivial answer to this question but i was  unable to find it.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want. There are multiple timestamps per group, so it is unclear what you mean by the difference between two timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to sum the difference between the first and last timestamp per group. That would be:

```
select group_id, timestamp_diff(max(datetime), min(datetime), minute) as timediff
from `xx.yy.zz`
group by group_id
```